# Access denied error when downloading file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I am getting access denied error when I try to run the below script to download the files from NSE sites. If I use the same URL in a web browser then the files can be downloaded.

```
$out="H:\Trade_Folder\HTTP\unzipped"
for ($i=1;$i  -le 6;$i++) {
    $year =(Get-Date -Year 2015 -Month 01 -Day $i -Format "yyyy")
    $monthname = ( Get-Date -Year 2015 -Month 01 -Day $i -Format "MMM").ToUpper()
    $day = ( Get-Date -Year 2015 -Month 01 -Day $i -Format "dd")
    $url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/$year/$monthname/cm" + $day + $monthname +$year + "bhav.csv.zip"
    $start_time = Get-Date
    $outpath = $out +$day+$monthname+$year+".csv.zip"

    [Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol =[Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12

    Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Url -Outfile $outpath
    Write-Output "Time taken: $((Get-Date).Subtract($start_time).Seconds) second(s)"
    expand-archive -path $outpath -destinationpath 'H:\Trade_Folder\HTTP'
}
```

Comment: So what is probably happening is those files do not exist. Instead it creates the files when you click a link and then allows you to download it. Can you post the Link where you click to download the data?

Comment: Here is the link https://www1.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/archieve_eq.htm  where you can select the required date to download the file

Comment: I don't think the provider allows automated downloads. If you put this in the browser address bar `https://www1.nseindia.com/content/historical/EQUITIES/2015/JAN/cm04JAN2015bhav.csv.zip` you will also see `Access Denied`

Comment: Is there any way in powershell to pass this as a browser request.

Comment: This is the address you are looking for `https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=16-04-2020&section=EQ` This will create the file and give you the link to the file to download

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
$SaveFilePath = "C:\Test\"
$Date = "16-04-2020"

$Response = Powershell -command "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date=$Date&section=EQ'"

$Regex = [Regex]::new('(?<=a href\=)(.*)(?= target=new)')
$Regex = $Regex.Matches($Response)

$OutFile = "$SaveFilePath$($Regex.value.Remove(0, ($Regex.value.LastIndexOf("/") + 1)))"

$Response = Powershell -command "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www1.nseindia.com$($Regex.Value)' -OutFile $OutFile"

"Saved To : $OutFile"
```

So there is a link that builds the file called :

`https://www1.nseindia.com/ArchieveSearch?h_filetype=eqbhav&date={Date Goes Here}&section=EQ'`

Then it displays a link to download the file.

Now on to the strange bit.

You can see i used `Powershell -command` to make the web calls

This is because for some strange reason I cant figure out... The site will not allow me to call it twice in the same powershell session. I tried calling a new runspace and still the same issue. So far the work around is to just call `Powershell -command`

Comment: I am getting below error when i run this script.Powershell : Invoke-RestMethod : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
At H:\Trade_Folder\newtest.ps1:4 char:13
+ $Response = Powershell -command "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www1.nsei ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Invoke-RestMeth...secure channel.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Comment: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At H:\Trade_Folder\newtest.ps1:9 char:28
+ ... veFilePath$($Regex.value.Remove(0, ($Regex.value.LastIndexOf("/") + 1 ...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
 
Powershell : The string is missing the terminator: ".
At H:\Trade_Folder\newtest.ps1:11 char:13
+ $Response = Powershell -command "Invoke-RestMethod 'https://www1.nsei .

Comment: @abhishekgaikwad to fix the `The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel` add this to the top of the script `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12`

Comment: I was able to download the file through this script.I will run this script in loop to see if I can get the files for multiple date. Thank you so much for the fix. It helps.